# How to manage scheduled maintenance in iOS Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, scheduled-tasks, freeze

I am looking for a way to be able to handle scheduled maintenance in iPhone app. We are using web services(.Net/C#) in our application and recently we have increased number of servers to maintain trafic on website. So whenever web team uploading website, they are displaying website is on scheduled maintenance. for iPhone, i have written below code to handle timeout at the same time.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

it will notify to user after 60.0 Sec. so users are complaining about **Freezes** iPhone application. Is there any other way to handle this? or Is there any other way to open any particular screen at the time of scheduled maintenance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Make your servers return an error code, then handle it.  Waiting 60 seconds is.... Perverse

Comment: If you can show a special pages to regular web users, then you can setup your server to return a special result to your app. As CodaFi said, handle the code so your app responds to the user more quickly with an appropriate message. Regardless of this, make sure you are doing all Internet access in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 7 silent background notifications might work for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute this code on a separate thread. The easiest way to do this is using Grand Central Dispatch, like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    // Add code to handle returningResponse.

    // Error handling
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured! %@", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or use the asynchronous version of `NSURLConnection` (either the old delegate way or with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`).

Comment: Neat! Didn't even notice that... It's just a bit more involved than wrapping the whole thing into GCD.